# Scala 'sbt' how to add the app build information to jar file?

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I have "build.sbt" file like this:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "AppName",
    version := "1.0",
  )
```

I compiling source like this in PowerShell:

```
$process = Start-Process -FilePath (Join-Path $sbtHome "sbt.bat") -ArgumentList "assembly" -Wait -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Then I get this jar file "AppName-assembly-1.0.jar".
Then right mouse click on it and select "Properties" and then "Details" tab. And there I neither see app name nor version information:
[image]

**Q:** How to make that the Version and AppName was saved/shown in Properties window "Details" tab, not only were reflected in jar name?

In example like in one of the app.exe file:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have set installed on your computer.

- Open terminal,
- Navigate to the folder where `build.sbt` is located (`cd /path/to/)`
- `sbt assemblyPackageDependency`
- `sbt package`

This will create standalone jar with all dependencies in `target/scala-2.x.y/project_name_2.x.y-zz.jar`, that should have app name and version number.

Comment: Yest it has the version and App name in file name. But in Properties window "Details" tab there no information written - if I rename file the information about app name and version will be unknown.